When associacion lists start getting outperformed by hash maps?
An association list is a list of key-value pairs, e.g. ( (key1 . val1) ... (keyN . valN) ) in lisp. Intuitively, when such a list is relatively small, a linear search should perform not worse or better than searching a hash map. I want to get a more precise answer on when exactly it is the case. For the sake of argument, let's say that we are talking here about a list implemented using a modern, optimized array data structure vs a modern, optimized hash map implementation. I'm asking only about the search performance.
Under what conditions exactly association lists would perform better than hash maps?

I doubt this question can get a more useful answer than just "when the programmer tested both, and one was more efficient than the other".
Within the rather broad constraints of the question, there are too many things that can affect the result, for example:

speed of calculating the hash of the object

a generic hash table versus a hash table tailored for the specific use case

random data versus real-world data

cache locality, processor family, and other stuff affecting micro-optimizations


Depending on these, I can readily imagine a list outperforming a hash table up to 5 entries or up to 50 entries, or maybe even a broader range.
This, in my view, leaves the question without a possible satisfactory answer.
